# Errno::ETXTBSY: Text file busy @ unlink_internal

Tags: ruby-on-rails, vagrant, virtualbox

The error:

Errno::ETXTBSY: Text file busy @ unlink_internal - /home/vagrant/shared/sample_app/db/test.sqlite3
/home/vagrant/shared/sample_app/test/test_helper.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
/home/vagrant/shared/sample_app/test/helpers/static_pages_helper_test.rb:1:in`'
Tasks: TOP => test:run => test:units
(See full trace by running task with --trace)

Answer (score 5):

Move the database files outside vagrant share, for example to /tmp.

edit database.yml:

```
development:
  <<: *default
  database: /tmp/project/development.sqlite3

test:
  <<: *default
  database: /tmp/project/test.sqlite3
```

Comment: thanks, this helped me on VirtualBox too (I'm not using vagrant), I just moved the db file out of the shared folder

Answer (score 4):

**Workaround:**

The error was related to Vagrant (or VirtualBox) custom shared folders. I couldn't figure out how to solve it, but there is a workaround. Instead of working with a vagrant custom shared folder **(~/shared/sample_app)**, defined in the *vagrantfile* I moved the app folder to a standard shared folder inside the VM root **(/vagrant)**. Now I still get the file sync in my host machine and the issue is gone.

---

**UPDATE 1**

Reached another conclusion today.
Everytime `bundle exec rake db:migrate` or `rails generate migration` is executed the error will return.

**Another Workaround** 
1 - Delete the *test.sqlite3* file.
2 - Copy the development.sqlite3 file 
3 - Paste and change the name to test.sqlite3 
* - Just migrated for testing and this seems to be a permanent solution.

Comment: I just went through this with VirtualBox (sans Vagrant), and reached the same conclusion. I used ProcessMonitor on the Windows side to see if some other process was contending for the test database file while it was being created (as manually deleting the file first didn't help), for example a virus/network scanner or indexing process, but could find no answer. What made no sense was that it worked fine for over a month of normal development, and just stopped working one morning for no apparent reason (no change in my routine or configuration of which I was aware).

Comment: I also searched a bunch without finding an answer, so I'm wondering if this is some recent development. (I'm on the .18 version, haven't upgraded to .20 though I've been meaning to, but at the same time it wasn't an upgrade that changed things.)

Comment: And to reiterate, my solution was to move the project in question outside of the directory shared with my Windows host, to a different one inside my Linux guest OS. (And as mentioned, this is with VirtualBox only and not Vagrant, in case others find this question.)

Comment: @TK-421, Try deleting test.sqlite3, copying development.sqlite3 and renaming it "test". You may be able to keep the sharing perks.

Comment: Works perfect! I am facing the same error when running `rspec`. Does anyone know why this is happening?

Comment: My colleague just got this error and it was because he was using files in a shared folder with windows.  Moved it into another folder and the problem no longer occurs.