# Error when running bin/rails test in Vagrant

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, activerecord, vagrant

I'm running the [rails-dev-box](https://github.com/rails/rails-dev-box) on Vagrant, with a folder shared between the box and my Windows computer. Rails version 5.0.5. I have a very basic app using a sqlite3 database, and a basic generated scaffold for a model. When I ran `bin/rails test` I received this error:

> ActiveRecord::Tasks::DatabaseAlreadyExists

A link in [this GitHub thread](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/25673) pointed to [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27359778/errnoetxtbsy-text-file-busy-unlink-internal), and I followed [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40131400) - I edited `database.yml` to change the location of the databases to a location outside of the shared folder. I then re-migrated the databases with `bin/rails db:migrate`. This seemed to help a bit, because the next time I ran `bin/rails test` I received a different error:

> Migrations are pending. To resolve this issue, run:
>   bin/rails db:migrate RAILS_ENV=test

But even after running `bin/rails db:migrate RAILS_ENV=test` I still receive this error each time I try to run the test.

Answer (score 0):

I think all you need is `bin/rails db:test:prepare` before `bin/rails test`